# auth()->guard('user')->user() not working jenssegers mongodb

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel-5.4

I am using Laravel 5.4 and jenssegers/mongodb.
I am using `use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Auth\User as Authenticatable;` for default auth functionality of `laravel 5.4 Auth`.
But I can't login because `auth()->guard('user')->user()` is not working.

Comment: are you facing any error? or edit question and upload code

Comment: @Bilal No, i am not getting any error but "auth()->guard('user')->user()" return blank(not anything) result.